# Find all zero-byte files in directory and subdirectories

Tags: linux, shell

How can I find all zero-byte files in a directory and its subdirectories?

I have done this:

```
#!/bin/bash
lns=`vdir -R *.* $dir| awk '{print $8"\t"$5}'`
temp=""
for file in $lns; do
    if test $file = "0"; then
        printf $temp"\t"$file"\n"
    fi
    temp=$file
done
```

But, I only get results in the current directory, not subdirs,
and if any file name contains a space then I get only first word followed by tab

Comment: You might like to read `man find`.

Comment: Question also posted on [unix&linux](http://superuser.com/q/575235/4714) - please don't post the same question in multiple places.

Comment: next time im not repeate like this due to problem in my browser in with stackoverflow i posted in superuser but now the problem fixed by clearing history cookies and catche in ie so i asked again here

Answer (score 243, accepted):

To print the names of all files in and below $dir of size 0:

```
find "$dir" -size 0
```

Note that not all implementations of `find` will produce output by default, so you may need to do:

```
find "$dir" -size 0 -print
```

Two comments on the final loop in the question:

Rather than iterating over every other word in a string and seeing if the alternate values are zero, you can partially eliminate the issue you're having with whitespace by iterating over lines.  eg:

```
printf '1 f1\n0 f 2\n10 f3\n' | while read size path; do
    test "$size" -eq 0 && echo "$path"; done
```

Note that this will fail in your case if any of the paths output by ls contain newlines, and this reinforces 2 points: don't parse `ls`, and have a sane naming policy that doesn't allow whitespace in paths.

Secondly, to output the data from the loop, there is no need to store the output in a variable just to `echo` it.  If you simply let the loop write its output to stdout, you accomplish the same thing but avoid storing it.

Comment: can i filter a directory other than *.xml

Comment: There's also a convenient `-empty` option.

Comment: @WesleyBaugh with -empty option you get also directories with zero files inside

Comment: @IgorScabini If you want to limit to files you can do so with `-type f`.

Answer (score 49):

As addition to the answers above:

If you would like to delete those files

```
find $dir -size 0 -type f -delete
```

Comment: its not necessary to delete all the file of size 0 all the time.

Comment: then how to delete a file within a folder with size 0

Comment: `-exec /bin/rm {} \;` or `-exec /bin/rm {} +` will work on non-GNU `find` implementations as well, which does not support the non-standard extension `-delete`

Comment: Alternative for `find $dir -size 0 -type f -delete`: 
 
`find $dir -empty -type f -delete`

Answer (score 9):

No, you don't have to bother grep.

```
find $dir -size 0 ! -name "*.xml"
```

Answer (score 5):

Bash 4+ tested -
This is the correct way to search for size 0:

```
find /path/to/dir -size 0 -type f -name "*.xml"
```

Search for  multiple file extensions of size 0:

```
find /path/to/dir -size 0 -type f \( -iname \*.css -o -iname \*.js \)
```

Note: If you removed the \(  ...  \) the results would be all of the files that meet this requirement hence ignoring the size 0.

Comment: `-iname` is not portable to some non-GNU implementations of `find` See [here for a list of standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html) options